# A word for something that cuts through the noise

Tags: single-word-requests

The closest word I can think of is "signal" but I feel that reflects my technical background rather than something that would be generally recognizable.

EDIT: More details

I'm aiming to name a product that a client is releasing. We use artificial intelligence to reduce the amount of transactions that need to be checked. Hence, the product "cuts through the noise" to capture the signal that is required.

Hopefully that helps?

Comment: could you give us more context? Are you talking about a crowd, for example, and something cuts through that noise? We could use an example sentence of where it would be used.

Comment: 'Cut through the noise' is already idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the context, but if you think 'Signal' fits what you need, then you could describe something as `prominent` `conspicuous` `striking` `pronounced` or even just `audible,`  `attention-grabbing`, or `head-turner` might work too.

It's a great area for good similes though, "Cut through the noise like a hot knife through butter" "...like the parting of the red sea" "...like a scythe through a poodle" etc.